# Can I export only a range within a sheet using VBA?

Tags: excel, vba, export

I have only just started learning VBA and have built a small application that exports a particular sheet. I want to go one step further and only export a range from that sheet.

I've tried various different coding scenarios but to no avail.

```
Sub saveSheetToCSV()

    Dim myCSVFileName As String
    Dim tempWB As Workbook

    myCSVFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "EXPORT_" & VBA.Format(VBA.Now, "ddMMyyyy") & ".csv"

    ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Data").Activate

    ActiveSheet.Copy
    Set tempWB = ActiveWorkbook

    With tempWB
    .SaveAs FileName:=myCSVFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
    .Close
    End With
End Sub
```

Can anyone please confirm what code I would use to just export a range within a sheet? I'm trying to export just the range A2:D24 in the sheet called "Data", rather than the whole sheet as what the current code above does. Thanks.

Comment: What is the range you're trying to copy? And where are you trying to copy it to?

Comment: I've updated the original question, thanks.

Comment: `A2:D24` to `A2:D24` on the new worksheet? Just the values, or the formatting too?

Comment: Yes the same range on the new worksheet.. For the .csv file it would be just the values, however I may need to export it as an .xlsx file so in that case I would need the formatting, so if you know both I'd be grateful.

Answer (score 0):

Copy Range to new Sheet in new Workbook. Save As. Close.

```
    Dim myCSVFileName As String
    Dim tempWB As Workbook

    myCSVFileName = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & "EXPORT_" & VBA.Format(VBA.Now, "ddMMyyyy") & ".csv"
    'Create new Workbook.
    Set tempWB = Workbooks.Add
    'Copy Range
    ThisWrokbook.Sheets("SheetNameWithRange").Range("A1:Z40").Copy    
    With tempWB
        'Paste Range
        .Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Paste 'Or Paste as Values to not retain Links/Formulas
        'Save and Close
        .SaveAs FileName:=myCSVFileName, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
        .Close
    End With
```

Comment: Thanks but I get an error when running {.Worksheets(1).Range("A1").Paste}

Comment: Try the whole range, if you copied `Range("A1:C30").Copy` paste the same, `.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:C30").Paste`

Comment: So I amended the code slightly and used `.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:C30").PasteSpecial` and it now works. I could also use `.Worksheets(1).Range("A1:C30").PasteSpecial (xlPasteValues)` if I wanted to clear any formatting. Thank you @Ricardo A